# Nesting different classes in the same selector in LESS

Tags: css, less

I have 2 `article` selectors named `.style1` and `.style2`,

Expected CSS output:

```
.tiles article.style1 > .image:before {
    background-color: #f2849e;
}

.tiles article.style2 > .image:before {
    background-color: #7ecaf6;
}
```

My Attempt at LESS:

```
.tiles{
    article{
        .style1 {
          > .image {
              & ::before {
                  background-color: #f2849e;
              }
          }
        }
      
        .style2 {
          > .image {
              & ::before {
                  background-color: #7ecaf6;
              }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to do it as shown above but the CSS result I get is:

```
.tiles article .style1 > .image ::before {
  background-color: #f2849e;
}
.tiles article .style2 > .image ::before {
  background-color: #7ecaf6;
}
```

which in my opinion, refers the `.style1` and `.style2` classes as the children of `article`, and not the identifiers of the `article` selector.
How do you think should I write it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `&` [parent selector](https://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature) like:

```
.tiles{
  article{
    &.style1 {
      > .image {
          & ::before {
              background-color: #f2849e;
          }
      }
    }
  
    &.style2 {
      > .image {
          & ::before {
              background-color: #7ecaf6;
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also write it as:

```
.tiles {
  article.style1 {
    >.image {
      &:before {
        background-color: #f2849e;
      }
    }
  }
  article.style2 {
    >.image {
      &:before {
        background-color: #7ecaf6;
      }
    }
  }
}
```